# How to make iframe automatically adjust according to the contents using vuejs?

Tags: html, vue.js, iframe

I have:

```
<iframe v-if="showIframe" id="iframepbi" :width="iframeWidth" :height="iframeHeight" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true" :src="embedUrl" :scrolling="iframeScrolling" />

<script>

export default {
  name: 'NameDashboard',
  components: {},
  data() {
    return {
      showIframe: false,
      iframeWidth: '100%',
      iframeHeight: '550',
      iframeScrolling: 'auto'
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.embedReport()
  },
  methods: {
   this.showIframe = true
   ...
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

The contents are differents graphics from powerBI and i want my iframe automatically adjust according to the contents. I aprecciate any help.

Comment: Is the iframe loading from a different domain?

Comment: Yes! Im loading from another domain

Comment: I don't think you can access iframe content from a different domain with JS

Comment: Nothing is impossible,  but I think you're going to have to get real creative to achieve this,  like a headless chrome browser running on the backend that loads the iframe content to check its size,  then pass the dimensions to the front end.

Comment: Sorry for long time without answers, I had some health problems but let go. I understand, so if iframe come from external domain him does not have access to the front-end settings? I understand alright?

Comment: correct, I believe this is a security feature coming from the browsers, no access from js to a cross-domain page loaded in an iframe

Comment: Oh gody! Alright, i will search for something. Thank you very much for help